# How to make it possible (in Ubuntu 14.04) to change name of a file with just 2x clicking on it?

Tags: mouse, rename

How to make it possible to change name of a file with 2x clicking on it (like in Windows), without right-clicking and then 'rename'?

Comment: I don't think you can. However, you can click once and press F2 to rename a file.

Answer (score 2):

You can press the **`F2`** key on your Keyboard after clicking on the file you want to Rename.

Just a reminder,  as some keyboards have take over the **F1-keys** by the **FN key**, therefore you might have to press **`FN + F2`**.

Good Luck!